# Do I have to worry about calling Repaint(); multiple times?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am currently developing a custom `EditorWindow` extension in Unity right now.

I have overriden the `Update()` function, and when certain conditions are met I call the `Repaint();` method to update the UI accordingly.

```c#
public class MyAwesomePlugin : EditorWindow
{
    ...

    public void Update()
    {
        if (condition_1())
        {
            ...
            Repaint();
        }

        if (condition_2())
        {
            ...
            Repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

My question is whether or not multiple calls to `Repaint();` in the same execution time-frame will cause multiple duplicate redraws, or is Unity smart enough to aggregate them and only redraw once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to create and set a flag variable `bool isDirty = false`.

```c#
public void Update()
{
    bool isDirty = false;

    if (condition_1())
    {
        ...
        isDirty = true;
    }

    if (condition_2())
    {
        ...
        isDirty = true;
    }

    if (isDirty) Repaint();
}
```

This bypasses the question, but any unnecessary function calls will adversely effect performance.

If there are `return` statements in `Update`, after `isDirty` could be set to `True`, place `if (isDirty) Repaint();` before the `return`.